# Show that the Euclidean metric satisfies the law of the parallelogram.

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis

Show that the Euclidean metric

$$d(x,y)= \left(\sum^{n}_{i=1}|x_i - y_i|^2\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}, \forall x,y \in \mathbb{R}^n$$
satisfies the [law of the parallelogram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelogram_law).

I initially thought of writing the internal product in terms of metrics, because we know that the Eucliadian metric comes from the internal product $<x,y> = \sum\limits^{n}_{i=1} x_i y_i$, perhaps using the [Identity of Polarization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarization_identity)

But I cannot report the formula of the Law of the parallelogram with the Eucliadian metric.

Comment: The [section of the Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelogram_law#The_parallelogram_law_in_inner_product_spaces) does this using inner products